# Query list of servers for memory/cpu allocated

Tags: bash, shell-script

Running RHEL 6.2, trying to write a bash script to SSH to a list of remote servers, and write the CPUs and Total Memory to a file, one line per host in the following format:

```
HOSTNAME1    CPUS: 12    MEMORY: 64
HOSTNAME2    CPUS: 08    MEMORY: 12
```

Here is what I have so far, it doesn't work fully, what I'm running in to is the part where the system SSHs to run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `free`.

The bash script would be called like so: `./query_host_info.sh <DEST> <USER> <FILE>`

The file it reads the lists of hosts from is a one-per-line file of hostnames.

```
#!/bin/bash

# username to connect via ssh
USER=$2
# destination path/filename to save results to
DEST=$3
# source list of hostnames to read from
FILE=$1

# Iterate through line items in FILE and
# execute ssh, if we connected successfully
# run proc/info and free to find memory/cpu alloc
# write it to DEST path/file
# if we don't connect successfully, write the hostname
# and "unable to connect to host" error to DEST path/file
for i in `cat $FILE`; do
  echo -n ".";
  CHK=`ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" \
            -l $USER $i "echo success"`;
  if [ "success" = $CHK ] >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
    `ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $i "\
        printf "$i    ";
        echo "`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | awk '{a++} END {print a}';
        free -g | sed -n -e '/^Mem:/s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/p'`";" >> ${DEST}`;
  else
    printf "${i}\tUnable to connect to host\n" >> ${DEST};
  fi
done
# All line items have been gone through,
# show done, and exit out
echo ""
echo "Done!"
echo "Check the list 'checkssh_failure' for errors."
exit 0
```

Comment: You want to collect the results from the script on the host running the script, right?

Comment: this bash script will be stored on my machine locally, It will then iterate through a list of hostnames ($i), connect to each hostname,  query that hostname for its memory/cpu allocated. and then write that data to a file on my machine ($DEST), one per line on the $DEST file.

Comment: I think its related to nested quotes and i think im just getting a few syntax related issues..

Answer (score 2):

Just modified your script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# username to connect via ssh
USER=$2
# destination path/filename to save results to
DEST=$3
# source list of hostnames to read from
FILE=$1

[[ $# -ne 3 ]] && { echo -e "\nUsage: $0  <User> <ServerList> <LogFile>\n"; exit 1; };

func_ssh() {
    local Ipaddr=$1
    local Cmd="${@:2}"
    local LogIt=${DEST}
    ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $Ipaddr "${Cmd}"
    [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && printf "${Ipaddr}\tUnable to connect to host\n" >> ${LogIt}
}

GetTotalProcs="awk '/processor/{a++} END{print a}'  /proc/cpuinfo"
GetMemoryDetails="free -g | sed -n -e '/^Mem:/s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/p'"

# Iterate through line items in FILE and
# execute ssh, if we connected successfully
# run proc/info and free to find memory/cpu alloc
# write it to DEST path/file
# if we dont connect successfully, write the hostname
# and "unable to connect to host" error to DEST path/file
for srv in $(< $FILE );
do
    echo -n "."
    A="$( func_ssh $srv $GetTotalProcs )"
    B="$( func_ssh $srv $GetMemoryDetails )"
    echo "${srv} CPU: ${A} MEMORY: ${B}" >> ${DEST}
done

# All line items have been gone through,
# show done, and exit out
echo ""
echo "Done!"
echo "Check the list 'checkssh_failure' for errors."
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run the script like so?:

```
% ./query_host_info.sh <DEST> <USER> <FILE> > output.log
```

-or-

```
% ./query_host_info.sh <DEST> <USER> <FILE> | tee output.log
```

Additionally you can use a command list, wrap a bunch of commands in parens, and redirect their output to a file.

```
% (ls; ls; ls;) > some_output.log
```

Comment: I could absolutely do that, my problem though is getting the ` `ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $i "\
        printf "$i    ";
        echo "`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | awk '{a++} END {print a}';
        free -g | sed -n -e '/^Mem:/s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/p'`";" >> ${DEST}`;` to work properly.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed it wasn't working, let me take a look, it's definitely a escaping issue, but what you're doing is doable.

Comment: Figured it out one way, posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. two things.. SSH didnt like the concatenated proc/cpuinfo and free, and i reorganized how the commands are ran.. Probably a way better way of doing this but this seems to work..

```
#!/bin/bash

# username to connect via ssh
USER=$2
# destination path/filename to save results to
DEST=$3
# source list of hostnames to read from
FILE=$1

# Iterate through line items in FILE and
# execute ssh, if we connected successfully
# run proc/info and free to find memory/cpu alloc
# write it to DEST path/file
# if we dont connect successfully, write the hostname
# and "unable to connect to host" error to DEST path/file
for i in `cat $FILE`; do
  echo -n ".";
  CHK=`ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" \
            -l $USER $i "echo success"`;
  if [ "success" = $CHK ] >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
    A=`ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $i "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | awk '{a++} END {print a}'"`
    B=`ssh -q -o "BatchMode yes" -o "ConnectTimeout 5" -l $USER $i "free -g | sed -n -e '/^Mem:/s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/p'"`
    echo "${i} CPU: ${A} MEMORY: ${B}" >> ${DEST}
  else
    printf "${i}\tUnable to connect to host\n" >> ${DEST};
  fi
done
# All line items have been gone through,
# show done, and exit out
echo ""
echo "Done!"
echo "Check the list 'checkssh_failure' for errors."
exit 0
```

Comment: Rather than a `for` loop and an abused cat, [use `while` and `read`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). And you should use [`$(..)` instead of backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)...